# Neighborhood of the Origin in the Weak Topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am in difficulty with the following question. Let $H$ be a real infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and $u\in H\setminus \{0\}$. Let $V$ be an any neighborhood of $0$ in the weak topology on $H$. Is there a vector $v\ne 0$ such that $tv\in V$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\langle u, v\rangle\ne 0$?

I would like to thank all help and comments.

Comment: On the one hand, consider $V = \{ x \in H : \lvert\langle u\mspace{-3mu}\mid\mspace{-3mu} x\rangle\rvert < 1\}$, on the other, what do you know about vector space topologies on finite-dimensional spaces?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: I corrected that $H$ is an infinite-dimensional real Hilbert space.

Comment: Well, if you want to find out whether _all_ neighbourhoods have some property, it won't harm to look at one or two specific ones to check whether these have the property.

Comment: Ah, so the dimension was a typo and the second part of my first comment is obsolete. However, the first part is still relevant.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Thank you very much for your hint. I know the solution.

Comment: Time to change your user name then, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Thank you again. You are laugh at me, don't you?

Comment: Not at all. Just making a pun, since you see the solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10511/discussion-between-blindman-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the solution of Daniel Fischer, choosing $V=\{x\in H: |\langle u, x\rangle|<1\}$. 
Then $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in the weak topology. Let $v\ne 0$ such that $tv\in V$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\langle u, tv\rangle=t\langle u, v\rangle<1$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Hence $\langle u, v\rangle=0$.